# In material-ui, how can I set different theme-styles for different breakpoints?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

*This questions targets material-ui 1.0.*

When I create a theme with `createMuiTheme`, how can I set, for example for `typography.title`, different styles for different breakpoints? On a component level I can achieve this with something like this:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  title: {
    fontSize: 34,
  },
  [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
    title: {
      fontSize: 28,
    }
  },
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material-ui sure has a lot of different theming solutions. When you look for one that would be useful to you, you are looking for two things:

> 1. Creating a theme that can be applied to *component hierarchy*.

Doc page "[Nesting the theme](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/#nesting-the-theme)"

> 2. Changing single styling rules while keeping the others intact.

Doc page "[Customizing all instances of component type](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/#customizing-all-instances-of-a-component-type)"
and "[Typography API](https://material-ui-next.com/api/typography/#css-api)"

The key to make it work is to create a second theme that can see the breakpoints, and provide it with some special options for overriding typography:

```
...outerTheme,
overrides: {
  MuiTypography: {
    title: {
      [outerTheme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
        fontSize: 28
      },
    }
  }
}
```

I find the "Nesting the theme" example code suitable to test it on, so this is what it could look like: 
codesandbox.io/s/98192p85zy

EDIT: replaced the final code link to make it more useful an answer than just the examples from the docs.

Comment: I took your code and shrinked it down to the absolute minimum (https://codesandbox.io/s/nw0pllwr04). This seems to work, but it means I always have to use two nested <MuiThemeProvider>s and do all the real theming in the second one?

Comment: Well, the idea is to provide a base theme only at root level. The nested "realTheme" definition does not need to be in the same scope as "baseTheme" as long as there is one (see [possible refactor](https://codesandbox.io/s/jn7xvnvq93)). I also tried [a workaround](https://codesandbox.io/s/lpo0xlmky7) which works, but the warning message shows that it is not its intended use.

Comment: Ok, now I figured out another way to only use one <MuiThemeProvider>. Maybe this is more like what you were looking for: https://codesandbox.io/s/98192p85zy ? If so, I can edit the link in my answer to make it more useful.

Comment: This indeed looks very much like what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to work with **createMuiTheme** with the breakpoints methods.

If you check the createMuiTheme core, you will see that it uses the createBreakpoints class.

So, you can do like that:

```
// theme.js

import createBreakpoints from '@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints'
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const breakpoints = createBreakpoints({})

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        [breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
          minWidth: '200px',
          backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        },
      },
      wrapper: {
        padding: '0 10px',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
      },
    },
  },
})

export default theme
```

*(tested: @material-ui/core 4.0.1)*